# ListBox Flicker When Drawing Items

Tags: excel, vb.net, listbox

I have a form with a Listbox that is populated by the contents of column “A” in an Excel Worksheet. Column “B” represents the quantity of each item in column “A”.

Each item in the Listbox is either colored grey or black depending on whether the item quantity is zero or greater than zero.

The problem is the Listbox flickers a lot, causing the form to really slow down. I’ve tried setting the form to Double Buffered, but this doesn’t seem to make any difference.

I'm hoping someone can help me resolve this issue.

```vb
Private Sub P_List_LB_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles P_List_LB.DrawItem

e.DrawBackground()

DataRange = WS.Range("B1:B20")
For Each cell In DataRange
  If cell.value <> "0" Then
    e.Graphics.DrawString(P_List_LB.Items(e.Index).ToString(), e.Font, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, New System.Drawing.PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y))
  Else
    e.Graphics.DrawString(P_List_LB.Items(e.Index).ToString(), e.Font, System.Drawing.Brushes.Gray, New System.Drawing.PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y))
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That code doesn't make sense. Why do you have a loop in there? You're only drawing one item so why are you calling `DrawString` 20 times? You obviously didn't debug either, or you'd have seen that that is what you were doing. Presumably you have 20 items in the `ListBox` that correspond to the 20 rows in the sheet. No `For Each` loop. You need to get the one cell that corresponds to the one item being drawn when that event is raised. That's what `e.Index` is for.

Comment: Why even go back to the sheet multiple times? Just get the data once, package it appropriately and bind it to the `ListBox`. Each item will then contain the value to be displayed and the value to control how to display it. You could even do the conversion between value and colour at the outset and store the `Color` value in the item. There's then no need even for an `If` statement. Just get the `Color` from the item and pass that to `DrawString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really use Excel in VB so I'm not sure exactly how you would get a single cell but that's what you need to do. Something along these lines:

```vb
Dim rowNumber = e.Index + 1
Dim range = WS.Range($"B{rowNumber}:B{rowNumber}")

e.Graphics.DrawString(P_List_LB.Items(e.Index).ToString(),
                      e.Font,
                      If(range.Value = "0", Brushes.Gray, Brushes.Black),
                      New PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y))
```

If you want to take my advice from the comment and incorporate the colour into the item then you can build a list of objects containing data and colour first. Again, not exactly sure how you do that with an Excel range but you can work that out:

```vb
Friend Class CustomListItem
    Public Property Text As String
    Public Property Color As Color
End Class
```

Create a list of objects of that type from your range, with the `Text` being set from column A and the `Color` being set to `Black` or `Gray`, depending on the value in column B. Bind that list to the `ListBox` and display the `Text`:

```vb
P_List_LB.Items.DisplayMember = "Text"
P_List_LB.Items.DataSource = myListOfCustomListItem
```

Your code would then be like this:

```vb
Dim item = DirectCast(P_List_LB.Items(e.Index), CustomListItem)

e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text,
                      e.Font,
                      item.Color,
                      New PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y))
```

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney for your long and informative answer. I have implemented your suggestion (the first one at the top of your answer). Whilst this does improve the speed of the listbox loading the items, there is still a flicker (and delay) each time I click into or click out of the listbox. It seems like it's redrawing the items each time I do this. Do you know of any way to stop this? Thanks

Comment: @Patrick, I wouldn't be surprised if the delay, at least, is due to read data from Excel each time. Can you read all the data from Excel upfront and store it locally, making it faster to retrieve each time an item must be drawn?

Comment: Thanks again. It’s now working as I hoped. I added the data to an array which solved the the need to repeatedly read Excel.